# How to create all tables on database when application is loading?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm learning about Entity Framework and I want to create a project with it. I've use FluentNhibernate in my project but now I want to try Entity, but I have a doubt about how to create all tables(DBSet) when the application is loading. In my case I have 3 tables: `Cliente, Produto, Venda`, that I want to create when application is loading but I don't know how to do this.

How could I do this ?

trying

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext{
    public DatabaseContext():base("default"){
        Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DatabaseContext>());
        //Database.CreateIfNotExists();                
    }

    public DbSet<Cliente> clientes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Produto> produtos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Venda> vendas { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder){        
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Produto>()
                    .Property(p => p.valor)
                    .HasPrecision(9,2); // or whatever your schema specifies

        Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code First will help you. http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/what-is-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have all your DbContext and Entities setup and you are just asking about generating/updating the database, you are looking for Entity Framework's migration features.

Open Package Manager Console and run the following commands in your project:

```css
// Enable migrations to your project
Enable-Migrations

// Add migrations to your project
Add-Migration

// Update any changes to the generated database
Update-Database
```

More details here: 
https://martinnormark.com/entity-framework-migrations-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 1):

In the **OnModelCreating** method remove:

```
Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
```

i suggest you to read:
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

and about automatic migration:
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/automated-migration-in-code-first.aspx